# Which method should I use to implement this Storm topology?

Tags: apache-storm

I want to implement the following topology in Storm:

```
a1->a2->a3->a4
    |        |
     -<----<--


b1->b2->b3->b4
    |        |
     -<----<--
```

Note that a1, b1 and a2, b2 etc. are identical bolts. There are two identical streams but tuples passed between the bolts must remain within the stream. There is also a loop leading from a4->a2, b4->b2.

To implement the separate streams I thought of either using fieldsGrouping on a streamID field or creating a separate streamID for each stream. The latter option seems better but my implementation below seems inelegant.

```
builder.setBolt("a2", new A2(), 1).shuffleGrouping("a1", "streamA"); 
builder.setBolt("b2", new B2(), 1).shuffleGrouping("b1", "streamB");
```

And then continuing in the same vein to implement the second requirement:

```
builder.setBolt("a2", new A2(), 1).shuffleGrouping("a4", "stream1");
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you produce from A4 an element that will be checked as a spout tuple in A1 instead of a loop on A2? Or, is it a totally different operation that is done on A4 to A2 (not equal to A1 to A2)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What's happening in the stream is that a1,a2,a3 and a4 are sequentially processing a message. a4 may periodically receive a message from downstream (not shown in my diagram) which it must then pass on to a2.

Comment: You should document this case, I feel there should be something better to do. IMHO you should not "pancake" concerns in one Bolt. If possible it is best to separate this case in another bolt/stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this with directGrouping and different streams. So there is one stream going from a1->a2->a3->a4 and another going a4->a2. This way I can ensure no tuples pass between the A and B groups.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see with your implementation is that you have 2 instances of A2, which is unnecessary. You can just

```
builder.setBolt("a2", new A2(), 1)
       .shuffleGrouping("a1", new Fields("streamA") )
       .shuffleGrouping("a4", new Fields("stream1") );
```